# is PyMySQL well supported? and is it slower than than MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql-python, pymysql

I'm building a python3 app which requires high-speed connections. Being a pure python library, will PyMySQL be significantly slower than the C based MySQLdb in connecting and executive queries?

Is PyMySQL well supported for future versions of python?

If not, can anyone suggest a reliable alternative?

Comment: I'd be surprised if PyMySQL was noticeably slower than MySQLdb - the biggest time cost is going to be IO, and being written in C won't change your network speed.

Answer (score 5):

PyMySQL is implemented in pure Python while MySQLdb is C extension. PyMySQL is easy to install (and some times the only way) in some system while MySQLdb sometimes give problems.

But both are just MySQL python connectors.

> Why PyMySQL? MySQL is an immensely popular RDBMS, and you usually need
>   to talk to it when writing a web application in Python. The defacto
>   standard, MySQLdb, is a C extension module that has a reputation of
>   being difficult to compile, especially if you're on a Mac (like I am).
>   Additionally, end-users need to wait for new binaries to be compiled
>   for each new release of Python, and MySQLdb will never run on Jython,
>   IronPython, or PyPy (without something like cpyext or IronClad). We
>   also maintain 100% compatibility between Python 2 and Python 3, so all
>   advancements made on the 2.x trunk will be immediately available on
>   Python 3.
>
> We are developing a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb that "just works"
>   without the hassle of compiling and installing C extensions and
>   without worrying what platform you're on.

Source https://code.google.com/p/pymysql/wiki/Goals

Comment: The link you post hasn't seen developement since 2010. Developement has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

Answer (score 5):

Many projects use PyMySQL because it supports Python 3 (3.3 and up) as well as Python 2. At the time of writing it has over 650 forks on Github and over 60 contributors. There are regular updates and patches to it every couple of months or so and it's popular in the Python community for it's relatively easy installation and Python 3 support. **So all that said, yes, I would say it's well supported.**

Now for speed: since it's written pure Python whereas MySQLdb is C, you can expect PyMySQL to be slower. For an in depth analysis I suggest a look at the openstack link at the bottom of this post. Based on their testing, **PyMySQL was roughly 10x slower than MySQLdb**. However, with DB calls you are mostly IO bound anyways so the advantage of PyMySQL supporting gevent or something similar for asynchronous IO may make up for the speed depending on your application.

Sources:

1. https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL
2. https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/PyMySQL_evaluation

Comment: It's only 10x slower on CPython, a lot faster on PyPy